# HTML-Javascript validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation, function

Hey i want to check that there should not be any empty textboxes on submission. so i inserted a javascript on submit button but it does not work. All ID names are correct

```
function checkall()
{
    var a=window.document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var b=document.getElementById("lname").value;
    var c=document.getElementById("gender").value;
    var d=document.getElementById("dob").value;
    var e=document.getElementById("country").value;
    var f=document.getElementById("zip").value;
    var g=document.getElementById("email").value;
    var h=document.getElementById("pwd").value;
    if(a=="" || b=="" || c=="" || d=="" || e=="" || f=="" || g=="" || h=="" )
    {
        alert("bad");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("good");
        return true;
    }
}
```

The submit button code is given below:

```
<input type="submit" value="Register" onClick="checkall()"/>
```

Help me out. Where i might have gone wrong ??

Comment: What you have "gone wrong" so far is saying: "it does not work." Instead it should be something like "I debugged the code in IE9, there is no syntax errors, but XXXX does not happen as I expect".

Answer (score 1):

You need to call this function in the `<form>` tag and have it return the result of the function:

```
<form action="whatever" method="post" onSubmit="return checkall()">
```

Comment: not working john. i've tried that too. page goes to "whatever" checkall() is not called.

Comment: I DID THIS BUT STILL NOT WORKING. PAGE GOES TO SIGNUP.PHP
NO VALIDATIONS. WHY ?
<form name="signup" action="signup.php" method="post" onSubmit="return checkall()">

Comment: @user1870867 It might help if you posted the HTML form as well. If you edit your question and add this information, another set of eyes may see a mistake that you missed.